# Fatal Error when trying to build monero-core

Tags: development, monero-wallet-gui, build

I'm trying to follow the directions from here...

https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.1 x86 in VirtualBox.

When I get to "make" it gives me the following fatal error.

```
In file included from main.cpp:38:0:
src/libwalletqt/WalletManager.h:5:32: fatal error: wallet/wallet2_api.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:596: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got some help from radfish on github...

https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core/issues/52

Here's what radfish said...

> You need to manually merge monero-project/monero-core/PR # 14 in order
>   to build (alternatively use develop branch in this repo), because
>   monero daemon repo was updated to not build/install wallet lib/headers
>   by default (need to pass BUILD_GUI_DEPS=ON option to cmake).

Here's what I did...

```
$ git clone -b develop https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core
$ cd monero-core
$ ./build.sh
```

And the resulting binary was in ~/monero-core/build/release/bin/monero-core